# How to create a subset of document using lxml?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

Suppose you have an lmxl.etree element with the contents like:

```
<root>
    <element1>
        <subelement1>blabla</subelement1>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <subelement2>blibli</sublement2>
    </element2>
</root>
```

I can use find or xpath methods to get something an element rendering something like:

```
<element1>
    <subelement1>blabla</subelement1>
</element1>
```

Is there a way *simple* to get:

```
<root>
    <element1>
        <subelement1>blabla</subelement1>
    </element1>
</root>
```

i.e The element of interest plus all it's ancestors up to the document root?

Comment: You want all the ancestors of the selected element? What about siblings at different levels, should those be stripped out? Your example doesn't make it clear.

Comment: Yes those should be stripped out too.. the resulting subset should be the selected elements plus it's ancestors "emptied"

Comment: I would love to be proven wrong, but I don't think you're going to find a *simple* way of doing this, like doc_root.strip_everything_but_child_by_xpath('//some/xpath/element1'). You're going to have to walk the DOM based on where you find your element and strip out/remove nodes manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure there is something built-in for it, but here is a terrible, "don't ever use it in real life" type of a workaround using the [`iterancestors()` parent iterator](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#iterancestors):

```
from lxml import etree as ET

data = """<root>
    <element1>
        <subelement1>blabla</subelement1>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <subelement2>blibli</subelement2>
    </element2>
</root>"""


root = ET.fromstring(data)
element = root.find(".//subelement1")

result = ET.tostring(element)
for node in element.iterancestors():
    result = "<{name}>{text}</{name}>".format(name=node.tag, text=result)

print(ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(result), pretty_print=True))
```

Prints:

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <subelement1>blabla</subelement1>
  </element1>
</root>
```

Comment: Well I posted the question to see if there was an elegant, built-in solution. I ended up doing something similar to your answer, I fail to see why it is so "terrible" though. Certainly not very elegant but I think it works

Comment: I think building this as string is somewhat terrible. With `lxml.builder.E` it should be possible to do this without building XML via string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The following code removes elements that don't have any `subelement1` descendants and are not named `subelement1`.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")  # First XML document in question

for elem in tree.iter():
    if elem.xpath("not(.//subelement1)") and not(elem.tag == "subelement1"):
        if elem.getparent() is not None:
            elem.getparent().remove(elem)

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <subelement1>blabla</subelement1>
  </element1>
  </root>
```